# nodejs - get working directory of a child_proccess after executing cd command

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process

I have a simple web shell for controlling remote devices. I would line to implement cd command without calculating the new working folder on the shell side. On the device side there is a nodejs client spawning child process to execute commands and returning the response to the shell via socket connection.

This is the device part of the code. I would like to set out.folder to the new working folder of the child process after executing the command (to use it when spawning the next process). process.pwd() returns the  parent process folder, not child. Is it posible, or is changing the working folder purely a shell thing and the process has only one  permanent pwd?

```
  socket.on("console_request", (data) => {
    console.log("console_request", data);
    var out = {
      from: socket.id,
      to: data.from,
      location: env.location,
      platform: process.platform,
      name: env.myId,
      stdout: ''
    }
    var child = exec( data.line, 
      {cwd: data.folder}, 
      (error1, stdout1, stderr1) => {

      if (error1) {
          out.error = error1.message;          
      }
      if (stderr1) {
          out.error = stderr1;
      }
      if(stdout1){
        out.stdout = stdout1;
      }
      console.log(child)
      out.folder = proccess.pwd();
      socket.emit('console_request', out);
    });
  });
```

`